# [Anylogic]: how can i select the second nearest warehouse?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am using Anylogic to develop a humanitarian logistic supply chain. This model needs to send lorries from Armies stations to warehouses
from which to pick item to support people affected by eartquake and go to epicenter to drop them. This model have to select for each
lorries, nearest warehouse which have availabilty of items in it. For example, if the nearest warehouse has not availablity, lorries have
to select the second nearest warehouse which have availablity and go on it to pick item and go at the epicenter.
I realize this state chart in which I defined an algoyrthm that have to choose the nearest warehouse which have availabilty of items in it, as follow:

```
List <Magazzini> subsetlist = findAll(main.magazzinis, w->w.availabilty>0); 

// I select just warehouses with availablity

List <Magazzini> sortmag = new ArrayList<>();

sortmag = subsetlist;

for (Warehouses m : subsetlist)
    {
        
        distance.add(distanceTo(m));
        
        sortmag = sortAscending(sortmag, p-> p.distanceTo(m));  //anylogic function which sort agent according a condition (distances
                                    // from lorry in that case)
                
    }   
    
    moveTo(sortmag.get(0)); //move towards the first one warehouse of the sorting made in the for cycle
    System.out.println(sortmag); // just to print the result
    sortmag = new ArrayList<>();
```

Anyway, this algorythm doesn't work for all lorries which read it on the state chart (in the state named "at_warehouse"), but just for
the first one. Subsequently, all lorries "read" the same result elaborated for the first one.

How can I fix it? Please, answer just if you know Anylogic software and don't close this post. For any further infos, please answer and
I'll give you that. I need to fix this problem for my thesis work. Thank you so much.

PS: I've uploaded also a pic in which you can see lorry which starts from Salerno and go to Bari and not towards Naples, where there is a warehouse with availabilty.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxjF5.png)

[image]

Comment: So only the one object get sorted as the first object of   sortmag  ?

Comment: Can you also post the method sortAscending?

Comment: exactly, just the first agent (lorry, in this case) which "read" this algorythm go towards the first warehouse that has availabilty. The second one which "read" algorytm go towards the same warehouse of the first. So, all lorries towards one warehouse.

Comment: @Mirco0 public static <T extends Comparable<? super T> void sortAscending( List<T> list ) — Sorts the specified list in ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements.

Here's the link:

https://anylogic.help/anylogic/data/sort-collection.html#working-with-non-comparable-elements

Comment: what about creating a distance in the object Magazzini, setting the value for every object in a loop and then sorting the ArrayList?

Comment: @Mirco0 so you mean to create a new array list in the object Magazzini?

Comment: I mean creating a property in the object magazzini called distance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could first set the `distance` value in a loop and then sort the Arraylist,
in this case you also have to create a property called distance in Magazzini
like so

```
for(Magazzini m: subsetList){
    m.distance = distanceTo(m);
}
sortmag = sortAscending(subsetList, p-> p.distance);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: do I create a collection anywhere? It responds as follow:

"Description: distance cannot be resolved or is not a field"

And how do I set this list?  If I define in this way:

"List <double> distance = new ArrayList<>();"

Anylogic say:"Description: Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType"

Comment: Use `List<Double> distance = new ArrayList<Double>();` . You cannot define lists with primitives

Comment: @Benjamin I coded in this way you suggested but it gaves me error as follow:

"Description: distance cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: I meant to create a double variable inside the Magazzini object called distance

Comment: @Mirco0 Grazie Mirco, it has gone. You give me a huge help

Comment: @Mirco0 if I would change availabilty for each warehouse when each lorries come there, how can I do? I have a parameter (an object) in Magazzini which represent the initial availability for each warehouse. How can I scale it for each warehouse?

Comment: If the answer helped you and was the solution to your question you could accept my answer. I'm glad I managed to solve your problem

Comment: Can you explain better your problem? If you need ask an other question and link it here. I'll try to help you

Comment: @Mirco0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73101543/anylogic-how-can-i-manage-availabilty-of-warehouses here's the link. Thank you so much!