# How can I manage availability of warehouses?

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm working on a tool about humanitarian logistics. In this model I have some lorries which pick items for support affected people by an earthquake and, after picking them, go to eartquake epicenter to drop these items. I need to manage the availabilty of these warehouses: for example, if a warehouse has 5 items availables and lorries has a transport capacity by 2, availabilty have to become 3 for that warehouse. I need to realize obviously this process for all warehouse of my Supply Chain. I've dropped (as you can see in the pic that I've uploaded) a parameter (availability) in the class of the warehouses [named Magazzini]).

This is the algorithm that manages lorries movement, in which I need to code this command to change availabilty.

```
List <Magazzini> subsetlist = findAll(main.magazzinis, w->w.capacita>0);
List <Magazzini> sortmag = new ArrayList<Magazzini>();
List <Double> distance = new ArrayList<Double>();
sortmag = subsetlist;
System.out.println(sortmag);
for (Magazzini m : subsetlist)
    {
        m.distance = distanceTo(m); 
    }
    sortmag = sortAscending(sortmag, p-> p.distance);
    //main.magazzinis.cap = main.magazzinis.cap - 2;
    moveTo(sortmag.get(0)); 
    System.out.println(sortmag);
partenza = time();
```

I write a possible command to do it, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: So do you need to check if the nearest wearhouse has enougth resources for the lorry and if not go to the next nearest wearhouse? Am I correct?

Comment: @Mirco0 correct. But this is implemented already thanks this algorithm.  I need to update availability of warehouse (number of items) each time a lorry get on it and pick 2 items (lorries have a capacity by 2).

Comment: Oh, do you mean `sortmag.get(0).cap -= 2;` ?

Comment: @Mirco0 exactly. I need to recall availability of each warehouses. Cap it’s capacita parameter in Magazzini (second pic that I’ve uploaded).

Comment: Putting the code inside `moveTo` could help? In this way everytime a lorry moves to a warehouse the warehouse's availability decreases by two, can you post the `moveTo` method?

Comment: @Mirco0 
Here’s the link of move to function

https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/movement-gis.html#movement-with-moveto-functions-moving-an-agent-toward-a-destination

anyway, what you said about decreasing it’s what I need to do

Comment: What about using `sortmag.get(0).cap -= 2;` right after `calling moveTo();` ?

Comment: @Mirco0 could you help me with this question? Thanks so much.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73169822/anylogic-how-can-i-execute-my-model-ciclically

Comment: @Mirco0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73601064/anylogic-how-to-get-value-parameters-into-excel-file

Could you help me please? Thank you.