# Anylogic: How can I execute my model cyclically?

Tags: java, anylogic

I need to collect some data for about 600 earthquake historic events in my model. I dropped in my model two variables which read latitude and longitude from excel file named "epicentri" (epicenter). In this file there are historic earthquake events with latitude and longitude. I need to run my model and, during this run, execute all of 600 events with each event having different latitude and longitude value.

The function that I currently use is:

```
latitude = epicentri.getCellNumericValue("epicentri", i, 2);

longitude = epicentri.getCellNumericValue("epicentri", ii, 2);

i = 2;

ii = 2;
```

I need to stop the simulation and start it again but updating these values that I need to recall rows in excel file that is linked to my model, all of this executing my model cyclically.

I found these commands on Anylogic that help to restart simulation during a single run (that I coded in an event object in the pic), that I've inserted in an event object, but I can't update `i` and `ii` values to select next earthquake event from my excel file.

```
new Thread() {
public void run() {
  // stops the model
  getExperiment().stop();
  try {
    // delay
    this.sleep(1000);
  } catch(Exception e) {};
  // runs it again
  getExperiment().run();
  getExperimentHost().setPresentable( getEngine().getRoot() );
}
}.start();
```

How can I do this? Thanks so much.

[image]

Comment: What does `getExperiment().run(); ` do?

Comment: Where does your first code snippet run?

Comment: @Mirco0 I took this code from Anylogic online help. This allows me to restart ciclically the run.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you attempting to do it like this (starting a new experiment from within a model run)? Because you want to see the model animation each time? Is that required?

Plus why does each run need to only have one earthquake (which is what you seem to be suggesting, though it's not completely clear)? Why can you not handle multiple sequential earthquakes in a single run?

If you want 1 earthquake per run, by far the simplest method is just set up a Parameter Variation experiment, where the model has a single (integer) parameter (which is varied from 1 to N) which determines the Excel row to use for this run. But this will do the runs in 'batch' without the animation. You can still use your Simulation experiment to show with-animation runs for specific individual earthquakes.

The code you have here can work for 'looped' with-animation runs but, because you need to set the state of the new model instance (`i` and `ii`) *before* it starts running, you probably need to use code inside your Thread's `run` method that is more like that in a Custom Experiment, where you explicitly instantiate an instance of your model (`Main`) and can then set up parameters/variables before you actually start it. (With the current code, you have access to `Main` via `getEngine().getRoot()` but the run has already started at this point.) See [the Usage Notes in the Custom Experiment help page](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/custom-experiment.html#usage-notes).

[I'm not going to post sample code for this because it's not clear that you actually need it yet, and this might be enough detail to get you there anyway if you do need it.]

But this approach also has to make sure that the current run ends just after you've started the next (unless I'm misunderstanding the requirements or you just leave each run to naturally finish via experiment end time/date without any further earthquakes...) which it seems you haven't included. (Otherwise you will have active threads for the initial run and every run you've started.)

Comment: Stuart Rossiter I can’t use experiment section. I never used it, so I thinked to follow this way.

Comment: Sorry what does "can't use" mean? That you don't know how to use experiments other than Simulation?