# ANYLOGIC : How to get value parameters into Excel file?

Tags: java, anylogic

I've created an agent parameter which saves travel time of lorries in my model. I would get these values (one for each lorries agent) in a Excel file. How can I do? I've uploaded a pic in which you can see on the right the focused parameter of which get value for each agent.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is better to define these types of data as variables, not parameters.

If you want to write the values of `tempo_viaggio` at the end of the simulation into an Excel file, do the following:

Drag and drop ExcelFile object, link it to the file that you would like to write to:
[image]

You need to define a variable to keep the travel times information in the Main agent. As an example below:
[image]

In the course of the simulation, populate the variable as following inside the `Tir` agent:

```
main.travelTime.add(this.tempo_viaggio);
```

At the end of the simulation, write this information into an Excel File.

```
for (int i=0; i<travelTime.size();i++)
{

    Double z = ((Double) travelTime.get(i));
    excelFileOutput.setCellValue(z, 1, i+2, 2); //value,sheetName or number, row, column

}
```

Comment: @Alfonso, glad that it helped. Could you please upvote/accept this as answer so that others can also benefit.